# Use merge() to update a data frame with values from a second data frame

Tags: r, join, merge

I'm trying to figure out how to use `merge()` to update a data frame.

Take for example the data frame `foo`

```
foo <- data.frame(index=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), value=c(100, 101, NA, NA))
```

Which has the following values

```
index value
1     a   100
2     b   101
3     c    NA
4     d    NA
```

And the data frame `bar`

```
bar <- data.frame(index=c('c', 'd'), value=c(200, 201))
```

Which has the following values:

```
 index value
1     c   200
2     d   201
```

When I run the following `merge()` function to update the values for `c` and `d`

```
merge(foo, bar, by='index', all=T)
```

It results in this output:

```
 index value.x value.y
1     a     100      NA
2     b     101      NA
3     c      NA     200
4     d      NA     201
```

I'd like the output of `merge()` to avoid the creation of, in this specific example, of `value.x` and `value.y` but only retain the original column of `value`  Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: What the result should be in case of no nulls?

Comment: Did you ever get answer to this question? I am looking for a solution for this same problem.

Comment: I wonder too why merge does not have, say an `overwrite=TRUE` parameter which would kick in when `by` is provided. It is incovienent to delete columns manually every time you want to want to rerun a merge.

Comment: See also: [Replace missing values (NA) in one data set with values from another where columns match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638845/replace-missing-values-na-in-one-data-set-with-values-from-another-where-colum)

Comment: I just had the same issue and I think the most direct answer to your question is the answer by @jangorecki below which you should accept

Answer (score 16):

The optimal solution using `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(foo)
setDT(bar)
foo[bar, on="index", value:=i.value]
foo
#   index value
#1:     a   100
#2:     b   101
#3:     c   200
#4:     d   201
```

first argument in `[` data.table method is named `i` thus we can refer to column from table in `i` argument using `i.` prefix.

Comment: How would you do this if there were multiple columns that needed to be updated, say value1, value2, etc.?

Comment: This data.table solution seems to be an ideal replacement for VLOOKUP. Merging or joining dataframes in R does not allow individual values to be updated, which is how this function is often used in excel.

Comment: @harisf, I would do this: ```foo[bar, on="index", `:=` (value1=i.value1, value2=i.value2)]```

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't `merge()` always bind columns together? Does `replace()` work?

```
foo$value <- replace(foo$value, foo$index %in% bar$index, bar$value)
```

or `match()` so the order matters

```
foo$value[match(bar$index, foo$index)] <- bar$value
```

Comment: One wrinkle with using `replace()` is that if the ordering in `bar` is not the same as in `foo`, it won't work properly.  For example, if you try running the above example after `bar <- bar[c(2,1),]`, the end result does not come out correct.

Comment: Yes, `match()` does work for my example.  In reality, it turns out that my actual use case is more complicated, where I would like to match across multiple columns and not just a simple vector. I don't think `match()` works when you would like to match across multiple columns of a dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! the idea to use the match() is good... however, if bar is to have another element that is not contained in foo (we want to update and add the new stuff)
    bar <- data.frame(index=c('c', 'd','e'), value=c(200, 201,215))
Then when we try to use match, we get an error. 
Error in foo$value[match(bar$index, foo$index)] <- bar$value : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
Any ideas how to overcome that?

Comment: What if you have multiple columns for indices?

Answer (score 4):

I would also like to present an sql-solution using library sqldf and the R integrated sqlite-database. I like the simplicity, accuratness and power of sql.
Accurateness: since I can exactly define which object=rows I want to change without considering the order of a data.frame (`foo.id = bar.id`).
Power: in WHERE after SET and WHERE (third row) I can define all conditions I want to consider to update.
Simplicity: the syntax is more readable than using index in vectors, matrix or dataframes.

```
library(sqldf)

# I changed index to id since index does not work. 
#   Obviously index is a key word in sqlite.

(foo <- data.frame(id=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), value=c(100, 101, NA, NA)))
(bar <- data.frame(id=c('c', 'd'), value=c(200, 201)))

sqldf(c(paste("UPDATE foo"
             ," SET value = (SELECT bar.value FROM bar WHERE foo.id = bar.id)"
             ," WHERE value IS NULL"
             )
        , " SELECT * FROM main.foo"
    )
)
```

Which gives

```
  id value
1  a   100
2  b   101
3  c   200
4  d   201
```

Similar issues:
[r equivalent of sql update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487711/r-equivalent-of-sql-update)
[R sqlite: update with two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273656/r-sqlite-update-with-two-tables-gives-syntax-error-near)

Comment: The SQL statement can run over multiple lines so `paste` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

`merge()` only merges in new data. For instance, if you had a data set of average income for a few cities, and a separate data set of the populations of those cities, you would use `merge()` to merge in one set of data into the other.

Like apeescape said, `replace()` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be:

1. Remove the NAs from the first data fram
2. Use rbind to append the data instead of using merge:

These are the original two data frames:

```
foo <- data.frame(index=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), value=c(100, 101, NA, NA))
bar <- data.frame(index=c('c', 'd'), value=c(200, 201))
```

(1) Use the negation of is.na to remove the NAs:

```
foo_new <- foo[!is.na(foo$value),]
```

(2) Bind the data frames and you'll get the answer you were looking for

```
new_df <- rbind(foo_new,bar)

            new_df
            index value
            1     a   100
            2     b   101
            3     c   200
            4     d   201
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way is to "mark" the value which need to be update prior to the merge.

```
bar$update <- TRUE
foo <- merge(foo, bar, by='index', all=T, suffixes=c("",".update"))
foo[!is.na(foo$update),]$value <- foo[!is.na(foo$update),]$value.update
foo$value.update <- NULL
foo$update <- NULL
```

It would be faster using 'data.table'

```
library(data.table)
foo <- as.data.table(foo)
bar <- as.data.table(bar)
bar[, update:=TRUE]
foo <- merge(foo, bar, by='index', all=T, suffixes=c("",".update"))
foo[!is.na(update),value:=value.update]
foo[, c("value.update","update"):=NULL]
foo

   index value
1:     a   100
2:     b   101
3:     c   200
4:     d   201
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue but this is still a specific case as compared to mine. I had 2 dataframes where left one was the master dataframe (like `foo` in your case) and the right one was minor dataframe with updated values (like `bar` in your case). Now I had to update the values in left dataframe from the ones in right dataframe only the values which were differing. It is somewhat similar to your issue but people have answered it with respect to NAs.

For more generic solution that is applicable to multiple rows and multiple columns with non `NA` values.

```
foo <- data.frame(index=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), value=c(100, 101, NA, NA))
bar <- data.frame(index=c('c', 'd'), value=c(200, 201))

ModifiedIndexs <-
  foo %>% 
  full_join(bar) %>% 
  group_by(index) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count > 1) %>% 
  pull(index)

UpdatedDF <- foo
UpdatedDF[which(UpdatedDF$index %in% ModifiedIndexs),] <- bar
```

Keep Coding!