# Data.frame merge usage for selective row replacement

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use merge() to update a table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190118/how-to-use-merge-to-update-a-table-in-r)

What is the proper use of merge for this kind of operation in R? See below.

```
older <- data.frame(Member=c("first","second","third","fourth"),
                       VAL=c(NA,NA,NA,NA))
newer <- data.frame(Member=c("third","first"),
                       VAL=c(2125,4587))

# 
merge.data.frame(older,newer,all=T)
  Member  VAL
  1  first 4587
  2  first   NA
  3 fourth   NA
  4 second   NA
  5  third 2125
  6  third   NA
```

That above is not exactly what I expect, I want to replace the older entries by newer ones, and not add another row. Like below. And I fail with merge.data.frame.

```
my.merge.fu(older,newer)
  Member  VAL
  1  first 4587
  2 second   NA
  3  third 2125
  4 fourth   NA
```

Kind of selective row replacement, where newer takes precedence and could not contain other Members than those in older.

Is there proper English term for such a R operation and is there prebuilt function for that?

Thank you.

Comment: If you use `by='Member'` and `all=TRUE` you get a new column with the structure you're looking for.  But I'm curious to know if you can use `merge` and return only that column.

Comment: There is similar question with two possible solution posted previously on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190118/how-to-use-merge-to-update-a-table-in-r/)

Comment: @Petr Could `newer` contain a `fifth` entry?

Comment: @Matthew Thanks for asking, no newer could not contain other Members than those in older. I made edit to add this important detail.

Comment: @Justin It looks like your hint could work well for me, at least small wraper function will do the job. Thank you very much for advice.

Comment: Thank you all for hints. Finally, I have chosen the method metioned in previously posted solution pointed out by Didzis. The method is older$VAL[match(newer$Member, older$Member)] <- newer$VAL, which gives me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You have effectively answered your own question.

If you want to deal with Matthew Ploude's point you could use

```
older$VAL[match(newer[newer$Member %in% older$Member, ]$Member, older$Member)
          ]  <- newer[newer$Member %in% older$Member, ]$VAL
```

This also the effect that where `newer` has multiple new values, it is the latest which ends up in `older` so for example

```
older <- data.frame(Member=c("first","second","third","fourth"),
                       VAL=c(1234,NA,NA,5678))
newer <- data.frame(Member=c("third","first","fifth","first"),
                       VAL=c(2125,4587,2233,9876))

older$VAL[match(newer[newer$Member %in% older$Member,]$Member, older$Member)
          ]  <- newer[newer$Member %in% older$Member,]$VAL
```

gives

```
> older
  Member  VAL
1  first 9876
2 second   NA
3  third 2125
4 fourth 5678
```