# R sqlite: update with two tables gives syntax error " near ".":

Tags: r, sqlite, sql-update

I would like to do a UPDATE with two tables on sqlite.

```
x1 <- data.frame(id = rep(1,3),
                  t = as.Date(c("2000-01-01","2000-01-15","2000-01-31"))
)
x1.h <- 0
x2 <- data.frame(id = 1, start = as.Date("2000-01-14"))
```

The UPDATE is:

```
sqldf(paste("UPDATE x1"
        ," SET x1.h = 1"
        ," WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *"
        ,"               FROM x2"
        ,"               WHERE x1.id = x2.id"
        ,"                     AND x1.t < x2.start"
        ,"               )"
        )
  )
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
   RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near ".": syntax error)
```

Has someone an idea what goes wrong? 
Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

Why are u using `sqldf` to update? I think `sqldf` is ony for `select` statement.

I would use `RSQLite` to this.

First I correct your sql statetemnt. I prefer use sep '\n' , to get pretty request with cat

```
str.update <- paste(" UPDATE x1"
            ," SET h = 1 "              ## here the error
            ," WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * "
             ,"              FROM x2 "             ## here second error 
             ,"              WHERE x1.id = x2.id "
            ,"               AND x1.t < x2.start "
            ,"       )"
      ,sep ='\n'
)


cat(str.update)
 UPDATE x1
 SET h = 1 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM x1,x2    ##
              WHERE x1.id = x2.id 
               AND x1.t < x2.start 
       )
```

Then you can do this :

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "x1", x1)            # I create my table x1
dbWriteTable(con, "x2", x2)            # I create my table x2
res <- dbSendQuery(con, str.update)   
dbReadTable(con,name='x1')            ## to see the result
```

**Edit**

I edit my answer after Op clarifications (`FROM x1,x2`  becomes `FROM x2`)

Comment: Tip: sometimes the best way to find SQL syntax errors is to learn to read the syntax diagrams: http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#update-stmt - the SET after an UPDATE takes a column name and not a table.column name.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the tip. But why are u saying it to me , is there  any problem with my answer?:)

Comment: @Spacedman no it is ok. good tip. it is always good to review the basics.

Comment: @agstudy. Updates with library(sqldf) are possible. I show it in my solution below. Thanks for your answer.  I learned another approach. Sorry about my errors. I forget to insert the row FROM x2. I'm not sure if your suggestion using FROM x1,x2 is correct.

Comment: @giordano read the help and specially the part The typical action of sqldf is to.... Whatever you use sqldf or Rsqlite the problem was a syntax problem. did you test it ?

Comment: @agstudy: yes. I tested the code. The error you are marked as second should be corrected to "FROM x2". Otherwise you will get h=1 in each row. This makes sense since the results of "SELECT x1.id FROM x1,x2 WHERE x1.id = x2.id AND x1.t < x2.start" gives 1, which is always true. There were 3 syntax problem. The one mentioned before, the one that for SET it is obviously not allowed to use table.column. These are both sql-syntex issues. Than the third is not a sql-syntax issue but one of the sqld library. After UPDATE the result should be returned by SELECT * FROM main.x1 (see solution below).

Comment: @giordano yes for `FROM x1,x2` ( you forget the from part so I add a one) I will correct my answer to fom x1, but really I recommand you using Rsqlite, it is the way for such manipulations.

Comment: @agstudy: Thanks. I agree with you regarding "such manipulation". Usually I do data management on a MySQL database and analysis in R (retrieving data from R with ODBC). sqldf I usually use for summary statistics of data frames and not for data manipulation. Question: I suppose Rsqlite is the interface for an external sqlite engine and not for the one in R, isn't it?

Comment: @giordano Rsqlite is exteranl. It is like csv files but with read/write operations in sql. In you case I would use RODBS:RMysQL to read/savs tables.  For summaries it is better to use R (plyr ,reshape2,..).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22587/discussion-between-giordano-and-agstudy)

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
x1$h <- 0
x1 <- sqldf(c("UPDATE x1
        SET h = 1
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT x1.id
                        FROM x2
                        WHERE x1.id = x2.id
                          AND x1.t < x2.start
                     )",
        "SELECT * FROM main.x1"))
```

Giving:

```
> x1

  id          t h
1  1 2000-01-01 1
2  1 2000-01-15 0
3  1 2000-01-31 0
```

Source:
https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#8._Why_am_I_having_problems_with_update?
Other things to remind: obviously alias do not work, for example UPDATE x1 a ...
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your inner SELECT doesn't say where its selecting from. Try it separately. I thought it should look more like:

```
SELECT * FROM x1,x2 WHERE x1.id = x2.id AND x1.t < x2.start
```