# r equivalent of sql update?

Tags: sql, r

I've looked around and I can't find a simple answer to this.
How do I do what in SQL would be an update table?
For example:

```
> df1 = data.frame(id=seq(1:3), v1=c("a", "b", NA))
> df1
  id   v1
1  1    a
2  2    b
3  3 <NA>
> df2 = data.frame(id=seq(1:3), v2=c("z", "y", "c"))
> df2
  id v2
1  1  z
2  2  y
3  3  c
```

How do I update df1 with values from v2 in v1, but only when id matches and when id > 2?
I've looked at data.table, but can't figure out the := syntax, and hoping there is something simple in base R? Desired output would be:

```
> df1
  id   v1
1  1    a
2  2    b
3  3    c
```

Answer (score 2):

**SQLite** One can use an update in sqlite via sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf(c("update df1 
         set v1 = (select v2 from df2 where df2.id = df1.id) 
         where id > 2", 
        "select * from df1"))
```

which gives:

```
  id v1
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
```

**MySQL** This works in MySQL:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(sqldf)

sqldf(c("update df1 
  left join df2 on (df1.id = df2.id and df1.id > 2)
  set df1.v1 = coalesce(df2.v2, df1.v1)",
  "select * from df1")
)
```

giving:

```
  id v1
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
```

**base R**  This also works.  The first two lines are just to convert v1 and v2 to character and they can be avoided if v1 and v2 were already character:

```
df1c <- transform(df1, v1 = as.character(v1))
df2c <- transform(df2, v2 = as.character(v2))
transform(df1c, v1 = ifelse(id > 2, df2c[match(id, df2c$id), "v2"], v1))
```

**Update**  Have incorporated comments and added base R solution.

Comment: Maybe this is bordering on an opinion / theoretical question.. but why isn't there a nice function in R to do what I thought would be a common & necessary database (or even dataframe) operation?  There are so many great functions in R to do almost everything else, I guess I'm just a bit surprised that this is complex.

Comment: Thanks for this - I think I might go this route.. seems much simpler to keep track of what I'm trying to match without brackets everywhere

Comment: @Grothendieck Thanks for this sqlite solution. I think the sql could be simplified. set-part: `set v1 = (select v2 from df2 where df2.id = df1.id)`. where-part: `where id > 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Updated to work when there are ids present in `df1` not in `df2`, and also if orders are different.  This works so long as there is only one `id` column:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=seq(1:5), v1=c("a", "b", NA, NA, NA), stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(id=seq(1:3), v2=c("z", "y", "c"), stringsAsFactors=F)

df1[df1$id > 2, -1] <- df2[df1$id[df1$id > 2], -1]
df1
```

Produces:

```
  id   v1
1  1    a
2  2    b
3  3    c
4  4 <NA>
5  5 <NA>
```

---

Here is a simple solution that works so long as both data frames have the same id set:

```
df1[df1$id > 2, ] <- df2[df1$id > 2, ]
```

Produces:

```
  id v1
1  1  a
2  2  b
3  3  c
```

Big note though, `v1` and `v2` need to be character, so run this before as they are `factor` by default:

```
df1$v1 <- as.character(df1$v1)    
df2$v2 <- as.character(df2$v2)
```

If you need to join on multiple columns or if the ids in one table don't all exist in the other you can use `merge` or `data.table` to get both variables on one table, and then construct the new column by combining the columns with `ifelse`.

Comment: ah, ok there are extra columns in both dfs, and there are extra ids in each id column.  how would the ifelse syntax work for each row? There isn't a more direct approach? It is so easy in sql..

Comment: something like this? `df1$v1[is.na(df1$v1)] = df1$v2[is.na(df1$v1)]`

Comment: @Paul, see update.  Note that multiple data columns isn't a problem.  This stops working if you have multiple id columns.