# Replace missing values (NA) in one data set with values from another where columns match

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame (datadf) with 3 columns, 'x', 'y, and z. Several 'x' values are missing (`NA`). 'y' and 'z' are non measured variables.

```
x    y z
153  a 1
163  b 1
NA   d 1
123  a 2 
145  e 2
NA   c 2 
NA   b 1
199  a 2
```

I have another data frame (imputeddf) with the same three columns:

```
 x  y z
123 a 1
145 a 2
124 b 1
168 b 2
123 c 1
176 c 2
184 d 1
101 d 2
```

I wish to replace `NA` in 'x' in 'datadf' with values from 'imputeddf' where 'y' and 'z' matches between the two data sets (each combo of 'y' and 'z' has its own value of 'x' to fill in).

The desired result:

```
x    y z
153  a 1
163  b 1
184  d 1
123  a 2 
145  e 2
176  c 2 
124  b 1
199  a 2
```

I am trying things like:

```
finaldf <- datadf
finaldf$x <- if(datadf[!is.na(datadf$x)]){ddply(datadf, x=imputeddf$x[datadf$y == imputeddf$y & datadf$z == imputeddf$z])}else{datadf$x}
```

but it's not working.

What is the best way for me to fill in the `NA` in the using my imputed value df?

Comment: Perhaps an example with sample input and output properly formatted?

Comment: Post the desired data frame that should result from the example.

Comment: k added my desired result granted col Z has more than 2 options

Comment: that data df has multiple instances of the y and z combination and i am only trying to switch out the NA values for values from my imputed dataframe, this appears to just merge the dataframes as one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1); setDT(DF2)

DF1[DF2, x := ifelse(is.na(x), i.x, x), on=c("y","z")]
```

which gives

```
     x y z
1: 153 a 1
2: 163 b 1
3: 184 d 1
4: 123 a 2
5: 145 e 2
6: 176 c 2
7: 124 b 1
8: 199 a 2
```

*Comments*. This approach isn't so great, since it merges the *whole* of `DF1`, while we only need to merge the subset where `is.na(x)`. Here, the improvement looks like (thanks, @Arun):

```
DF1[is.na(x), x := DF2[.SD, x, on=c("y", "z")]]
```

This way is analogous to @RHertel's answer.

---

From @Jakob's comment:

> does this work for more than one x variable? If I want to fill up entire datasets with several columns?

You can enumerate the desired columns:

```
DF1[DF2, `:=`(
  x = ifelse(is.na(x), i.x, x),
  w = ifelse(is.na(w), i.w, w)
), on=c("y","z")]
```

The expression could be constructed using `lapply` and `substitute`, probably, but if the set of columns is fixed, it might be cleanest just to write it out as above.

Comment: It would be nice if data.table allowed `DF1[DF2, x[is.na(x)] := i.x, on=c("y","z")]`

Comment: Or `dt1[is.na(x), x := dt2[.SD, x, on=c("y", "z")]]`

Comment: @Frank does this work for more than one x variable? If I want to fill up entire datasets with several columns?

Comment: @Jakob I've edited in one way above, hope it helps. If you're looking for help with something less manual (than writing a line for each column) maybe worthwhile to make a reproducible example and post a new question

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative with base R:

```
df1[is.na(df1$x),"x"] <- merge(df2,df1[is.na(df1$x),][,c("y","z")])$x
> df1
#    x y z
#1 153 a 1
#2 163 b 1
#3 124 b 1
#4 123 a 2
#5 145 e 2
#6 176 c 2
#7 184 d 1
#8 199 a 2
```

Comment: where you have the sequence 2:3 could i replace that with the c(df$y,df$z)?

Comment: what about when df1 has multiple values of x(including NAs) for z==1 & y==1

Comment: getting this error:   Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(dataimp$steps), "steps", value = c(NA,  : 
  replacement has 17568 rows, data has 2304

Comment: steps is my x and dataimp is my df1

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution, conceptually identical to the answers above. To pull out just the rows of `imputeddf` that correspond to NAs in `datadf`, use `semi_join`. Then, use another join to match back to `datadf`. (This step is not very clean, unfortunately.)

```r
library(dplyr)
replacement_rows <- imputeddf %>%
  semi_join(datadf %>% filter(is.na(x)), by = c("y", "z"))
datadf <- datadf %>%
  left_join(replacement_rows, by = c("y", "z")) %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(is.na(x.x), x.y, x.x)) %>%
  select(x, y, z)
```

This gets what you want:

```
> datadf
# A tibble: 8 x 3
      x y         z
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1   153 a         1
2   163 b         1
3   184 d         1
4   123 a         2
5   145 e         2
6   176 c         2
7   124 b         1
8   199 a         2
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, you can use `rows_patch` to update NAs:

```r
rows_patch(datadf, imputeddf, by = c("y", "z"), unmatched = "ignore")

#     x y z
# 1 153 a 1
# 2 163 b 1
# 3 184 d 1
# 4 123 a 2
# 5 145 e 2
# 6 176 c 2
# 7 124 b 1
# 8 199 a 2
```

---

data:

```r
datadf <- read.table(header = T, text = "x    y z
153  a 1
163  b 1
NA   d 1
123  a 2 
145  e 2
NA   c 2 
NA   b 1
199  a 2")

imputeddf <- read.table(header = T, text = " x  y z
123 a 1
145 a 2
124 b 1
168 b 2
123 c 1
176 c 2
184 d 1
101 d 2")
```