# Join complementary dataframes, no NAs where a value is available

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have two data frames with a unifying index v1. I need to create a third data frame with no NA values, if a number is available.

I have tried various combinations of the join functions from dplyr and the rbind.fill function in plyr.

```r
# Given
v1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
df1 <- cbind.data.frame(v1, v2 = c(1,NA,3,NA))
df2 <- cbind.data.frame(v1, v2 = c(NA,2,NA,4))

# I would like
df3 <- cbind.data.frame(v1, v2 = c(1,2,3,4))
```

How can I make this possible?

Comment: Or `setDT(df1)[is.na(v2), v2 := setDT(df2)[.SD, v2, on = .(v1)]]` as described here: [Replace missing values (NA) in one data set with values from another where columns match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638845/replace-missing-values-na-in-one-data-set-with-values-from-another-where-colum)

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to do a `full_join` on 'v1' and then `coalesce` the 'v2' columns

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by = 'v1') %>%
    transmute(v1, v2 = coalesce(v2.x, v2.y))
```

Comment: @Gainz ```setDT(df1)[df2, v2i := i.v2, on='v1'][is.na(v2), v2 := v2i][,v2i:= NULL][]``` I am pretty sure that I got this from akrun; I had this comment beside this line within one of my scripts saying credit goes to them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple base solution:

```
> df3 = df2
> df3$v2 = ifelse(is.na(df1$v2),df2$v2,df1$v2)
> df3
  v1 v2
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
4  d  4
```

the `ifelse` picks the number from one column or the other based on the NA nature of one column.

It doesn't cover the case if both or neither of the source `v2` columns are NA but there's none in your sample and you don't mention it...

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that I got this from [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118475/join-complementary-dataframes-no-nas-where-a-value-is-available#comment98870852_56118530) but could not find the thread. Posting an answer for future reference:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, v2i := i.v2, on='v1'][is.na(v2), v2 := v2i][,v2i:= NULL][]
```

```r
#>    v1 v2
#> 1:  a  1
#> 2:  b  2
#> 3:  c  3
#> 4:  d  4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

---

---

[@Henrik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118475/join-complementary-dataframes-no-nas-where-a-value-is-available#comment98871141_56118475) also suggested the following:

`setDT(df1)[is.na(v2), v2 := setDT(df2)[.SD, v2, on = .(v1)]]`

but I personally prefer the first solution over this mostly because of the sequence of getting the answer (joining dataframes first and replacing `NA` later).

Comment: You find some arguments for the "update join" idiom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54313203/1851712)

Answer (score 0):

We can use {powerjoin} :

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "v1", conflict = coalesce_xy)
#   v1 v2
# 1  a  1
# 2  b  2
# 3  c  3
# 4  d  4
```