# Complete missing column values with values from another table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have two `data.tables` like this

```
dt1 <- data.table(ID = c(1001:1010,1003,1003,1004),
                  CLASS_CODE=c(10,11,rep(NA,2),14,NA,16,NA,18,19,rep(NA,3)))

dt2 <- data.table(ID = c(1003,1004,1006,1008),
                  CLASS_CODE=c(101:104))
```

Note that there are some repeated ID's in `dt1`.

In `dt2` there are the missing ID's with some alternative CLASS_CODE's.

I would like to complete `dt1` using the values in `dt2`. I've tried to use:

`dt1[is.na(CLASS_CODE),CLASS_CODE := dt2[ID %in% dt1[is.na(CLASS_CODE),ID],CLASS_CODE] ]`

but the `%in%` don't repeat the last three IDs

Anyone would now a way to use `:=` in order to get it right?

I figured out an an alternative way using `merge` however I've still think that using `:=` would be faster/shorter.

Using merge:

```
dt1 <- merge(dt1,
             dt2,
             by = "ID", all.x = TRUE,sort = FALSE)

dt1[is.na(CLASS_CODE.x), CLASS_CODE.x := CLASS_CODE.y]
dt1$CLASS_CODE.y <- NULL
colnames(dt1)[2] <- "CLASS_CODE"
```

Comment: There seems to be a data.table answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54568079/2372064

Comment: [Replace missing values (NA) in one data set with values from another where columns match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32639171/1851712)

Comment: You are welcome @LucasRagni. The code suggested by Arun [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638845/replace-missing-values-na-in-one-data-set-with-values-from-another-where-colum/32639171#comment53298586_32639171) is _extremely_ useful for update-joins. That syntax is further described here: [Which data.table syntax for left join (one column) to prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312225/which-data-table-syntax-for-left-join-one-column-to-prefer/54313203#54313203). Cheers.