# Programming with dplyr, passing column name, same column in two tables

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to fill in NA values in one table with matches in another, similar to what's happening in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638845/replace-missing-values-na-in-one-data-set-with-values-from-another-where-colum).  However, I prefer a tidyverse/dplyr solution, and more importantly, I need to generalize this action to a function. Here's a MWE:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), y = c(1, NA, 2, NA, NA))
df2 <- tibble(x = c("g", "b", "d", "f", "a"), y = c(3, 4, NA, 5, 1))

# Find NA values in df1 which have matches (even NA matches) in df2.
df1 %>% filter(is.na(y) & x %in% df2$x) -> NAs_to_fill_in

# Get the corresponding values from df2.
df2 %>% filter(x %in% NAs_to_fill_in$x) %>% select(y) -> content_for_NAs

# Assign the values from df2 into df1.
df1 %>% filter(is.na(y) & x %in% df2$x) %>% mutate(y = content_for_NAs)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x       y$y
  <chr> <dbl>
1 b         4
2 d        NA
```

This roughly does the trick, except for a couple of problems:

1. The y column is now called y$y, and
2. This leans too heavily on base-R syntax, which I'm having difficulty building a function around.

One thing I've tried is using `select` in the first step, as in:

```
df1 %>% filter(is.na(y) & x %in% df2 %>% select(x))
```

but that gives the error

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "logical"
ℹ Input `..1` is `is.na(y) & x %in% df2 %>% select(x)`.
```

I don't wholly understand the error, as I am not explicitly using `select`, however, I'm also not surprised about it given the potential ambiguity inherent in passing the variable `x` from both tables around this way.

I have read the [Programming with dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), but I either don't understand it enough yet or else I'm missing something from somewhere else.

The desired function would do something like:

```
fill_in_the_blank <- function(df_with_NAs, df_with_values, column_they_match_on,
                              column_with_values_of_interest){ GOOD CODE HERE }
```

with output:

```
fill_in_the_blank(df1, df2, x, y)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  x         y
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 b         4
3 c         2
4 d        NA
5 e        NA
```

What is the correct, idiomatic way to fill in these NA values, and how may I generalize it to a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a "tidyverse" style approach

```
fill_in_the_blank <- function(df1, df2, common, update) {
  x <- ensym(common)
  y <- ensym(update)
  yvars <- syms(paste0(rlang::as_string(y), c(".x", ".y")))
  df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2 %>% select(!!x, !!y), by=rlang::as_string(x))  %>% 
    mutate("{y}" := coalesce(!!!yvars),
           !!yvars[[1]] := NULL, !!yvars[[2]] := NULL)
}
fill_in_the_blank(df1, df2, x, y)
```

We use `ensym()` to allow passing column names as symbols and then use `rlang::as_string()` as necessary to turn them into strings. This allows us to create the names of the variables that are created during the inner join using the default suffixes. Then we use `coalesce()` to get the non-NA values, then we drop the two "raw" values from the join.

Comment: Thank you, this is a big help.
As a follow-up, what would have to enable `common` to be a vector of multiple column names to match on?
(I promise I'm going to read up on how this works!  Just when I thought I was comfy in R/Tidyverse, I bump into `:=`, `!!`, and `!!!`, which are all quite new to me.)