# How to use merge or replace to update a table in R with multiple columns

Tags: r, matrix, merge, data.table

I want to do something VERY similar to this question:  [how to use merge() to update a table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190118/how-to-use-merge-to-update-a-table-in-r)

but instead of just one column being the index, I want to match the new values on an arbitrary number of columns >=1.

```
foo <- data.frame(index1=c('a', 'b', 'b', 'd','e'),index2=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2), value=c(100,NA, 101, NA, NA))
```

Which has the following values

```
foo
  index1 index2 value
1      a      1   100
2      b      1    NA
3      b      2   101
4      d      3    NA
5      e      2    NA
```

And the data frame bar

```
bar <- data.frame(index1=c('b', 'd'),index2=c(1,3), value=c(200, 201))
```

Which has the following values:

```
 bar
  index1 index2 value
1      b      1   200
2      d      3   201
```

merge(foo, bar, by='index', all=T)
It results in this output:

Desired output:

```
foo
  index1 index2 value
1      a      1   100
2      b      1   200
3      b      2   101
4      d      3   201
5      e      2    NA
```

Comment: Is there a reason `index2` is numeric for one data frame and a character for the other ?  Also, do you want to merge based on both `index1` and `index2` ?

Comment: No sorry, Arun edited it , thanks.  yes, merge based on both indices

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need a `merge` but more to `rbind` and filter them later. Here I am using `data.table` for sugar syntax.

```
dx <- rbind(bar,foo)
library(data.table)
setDT(dx)
## note this can be applied to any number of index
setkeyv(dx,grep("index",names(dx),v=T))
## using unqiue to remove all duplicated 
## here it will remove the duplicated with missing values which is the 
## expected behavior
unique(dx)

#    index1 index2 value
# 1:      b      1   200
# 2:      b      2   101
# 3:      d      3   201
# 4:      a      1   100
# 5:      e      2    NA
```

you can be more explicit and filter your rows by group of indexs:

```
 dx[,ifelse(length(value)>1,value[!is.na(value)],value),key(dx)]
```

Comment: I reckon this is a good approach, it's pretty straight-forward in base R too: `foo2 <- rbind(bar, foo); foo2[!duplicated(foo2[c("index1","index2")]),]`

Comment: Doesn't `foo[bar, on=c("index1","index2"), value := i.value]` do it?

Comment: @Frank - that's neat - so that's analogous to like an `update` statement in `sql`?

Comment: @thela I think so, yeah. I never thought of the analogy before now.

Comment: @robertevansanders you can add your own answer using this code. It is even recommendable to answer its own question in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an R base approach

```
> temp <- merge(foo, bar, by=c("index1","index2"), all=TRUE)
> temp$value <- with(temp, ifelse(is.na(value.x) & is.na(value.y), NA, rowSums(temp[,3:4], na.rm=TRUE)))
> temp <- temp[, -c(3,4)]
> temp
  index1 index2 value
1      a      1   100
2      b      1   200
3      b      2   101
4      d      3   201
5      e      2    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some *dplyr* voodoo to produce what you want. The following subsets the data by unique combinations of "index1" and "index2", and checks the contents of "value" for each subset. If "value" has any non-NA values, those are returned. If only an NA value is found, that is returned.

Seems a little specific, but it seems to do what you want!

```
library(dplyr)

df.merged <- merge(foo, bar, all = T) %>% 
  group_by(index1, index2) %>% 
  do(
    if (any(!is.na(.$value))) {
      return(subset(., !is.na(value)))
    } else {
      return(.)
    }
  )
```

Output:

```
  index1 index2 value
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
1      a      1   100
2      b      1   200
3      b      2   101
4      d      3   201
5      e      2    NA
```

Comment: You might be interested in the newer  dplyr function `coalesce`, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify as many columns as you want with merge:

```
out <- merge(foo, bar, by=c("index1", "index2"), all.x=TRUE)
new <- apply(out[,3:4], 1, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))
new <- ifelse(is.na(out[,3]) & is.na(out[,4]), NA, new)
out <- cbind(out[,1:2], new)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output, it gives columns .x and columns .y

Comment: You don't have to specify `by.x` and `by.y` if they are identical, just `by=` will do.

Comment: cool, I didn't know that! In this case foo and bar both have the same column **value** which causes my solution to fail if excluded.

Comment: @AidanGawronski - it shouldn't `identical(merge(foo, bar, by=c("index1", "index2"), all.x=TRUE), merge(foo, bar, by.x=c("index1", "index2"), by.y=c("index1", "index2"), all.x=TRUE))` returns `TRUE`

Comment: oh! I misunderstood what you meant. Thanks!

Comment: A coherent simple merge solution would have been nice though.  Anyone familiar with database management know what this type of merge I'm trying to do is called?  (Merging on an index to complete columns)

Comment: basically you are doing a join and then summing two columns.. The solution would be much more simple if you allowed NA's to be replaced by zeros.

Comment: `out <- merge(foo, bar, by=c("index1", "index2"), all.x=TRUE)`

`out[is.na(out)] <- 0`

`out <- cbind(out[,1:2], out[,3] + out[,4])`

`names(out) <- c("index1", "index2", "value")`